# Android ListView.count vs ListView.size

Tags: android, kotlin, listview

what is the difference between `count` and `size` in a `listview` in android ?

my listview shows `listViewMusic.count = 204` but `listViewMusic.size = 12` and i don't know why

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation says:

**listViewMusic.size** Returns the number of views in this view group.

**listViewMusic.count** return The number of items owned by the Adapter associated with this AdapterView. (This is the number of data items, which may be larger than the number of visible views.)

Comment: Thank you, but how come the size is limited to number of views shown on screen at any time ? how do i access a view that is further down the listview ?